# How do I use multiple spaces in a make variable/function?

Tags: string, escaping, gnu-make

Usually, make combines multiple consecutive white space characters. Sometimes this behaviour is unwanted. Here is an **example** for such a case:

```
.PHONY: help

help:
    $(info Usage: make [command] [VARIABLES])
    $(info )
    $(info command1 ..... Do what command1 does and)
    $(info                let the sentence continue.)
    $(info command2 ..... Description of command2)
```

### Wanted output:

```
Usage: make [command] [VARIABLES]

command1 ..... Do what command1 does and
               let the sentence continue.
command2 ..... Description of command2
```

### Actual output:

```
Usage: make [command] [VARIABLES]

command1 ..... Do what command1 does and
 let the sentence continue.                 # Not aligned with "Do" in line above
command2 ..... Description of command2
```

In other word's, is there a way to align or quote spaces in make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an old trick:

```
EMPTY=
SPACE=$(EMPTY) $(EMPTY)
```

So, in your case:

```
.PHONY: help

EMPTY=
SPACE=$(EMPTY) $(EMPTY)

help:
    $(info Usage: make [command] [VARIABLES])
    $(info )
    $(info command1 ..... Do what command1 does and)
    $(info $(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)$(SPACE)let the senten\
ce continue.)
    $(info command2 ..... Description of command2)
```

Answer (score 1):

First idea: don't use `$(info ...)` in the recipe.  Instead use a shell command like `echo` etc.  Then you can use quoting etc. to preserve whitespace.

Second idea, use a `define` variable definition to contain the complete contents:

```
define USAGE
Usage: make [command] [VARIABLES]

command1 ..... Do what command1 does and
               let the sentence continue.
command2 ..... Description of command2
endef

.PHONY: help
help: ; $(info $(value USAGE))
```

Comment: I like the `define` idea. As for echo: Shouldn't one use make built-ins as much as possible to be more compatible with different systems?

Comment: Well, make's built-in functions are not intended to provide any sort of compatibility layer that allows you to avoid operating system differences.  It's almost 100% guaranteed you'll need something else.  If make functions meet your needs then sure, it doesn't hurt to use them.  But if they don't do what you need then obviously using them is not feasible.